# django.db.utils.DatabaseError when added objects = models.DjongoManager() to Djongo mongodb model

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, django-migrations

I am getting `django.db.utils.DatabaseError` when trying to migrate my migrations. The only think I remember changing to my models is adding `objects = models.DjongoManager()` to my StockInfo model. I don't know if that causes a new migration but I am getting a very long error:

```
cchilders@cchilders-HP-ProBook-450-G3 ~/projects/stocks_backend (save_stocks_info_to_db)$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'dividends_info':
  dividends_info/migrations/0003_auto_20220814_1800.py
    - Alter field id on stockinfo
Migrations for 'users':
  users/migrations/0002_auto_20220814_1800.py
    - Alter field id on userprofile
cchilders@cchilders-HP-ProBook-450-G3 ~/projects/stocks_backend (save_stocks_info_to_db)$ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, dividends_info, sessions, users
Running migrations:
Not implemented alter command for SQL ALTER TABLE "dividends_info_stockinfo" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE int
  Applying dividends_info.0003_auto_20220814_1800...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 876, in parse
    raise e
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 857, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 889, in _alter
    query = AlterQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 425, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 441, in parse
    self._alter(statement)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 500, in _alter
    raise SQLDecodeError(f'Unknown token: {tok}')
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

    Keyword: Unknown token: TYPE
    Sub SQL: None
    FAILED SQL: ('ALTER TABLE "dividends_info_stockinfo" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE int',)
    Params: ([],)
    Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cchilders/projects/stocks_backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/cchilders/projects/stocks_backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 236, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 571, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 721, in _alter_field
    self.execute(
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

dividends_info/models.py:

```
from djongo import models


class Dividend(models.Model):
    date = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    amount = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class StockInfo(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dividends = models.ArrayField(model_container=Dividend)

    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

users/models.py:

```
from djongo import models


class RecentSearch(models.Model):
    search_term = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    searches = models.ArrayField(model_container=RecentSearch)

    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

my recent migration of stocks info:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.12 on 2022-08-14 18:00

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('dividends_info', '0002_stockinfo_ticker'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='stockinfo',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
        ),
    ]
```

recent migration of users:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.12 on 2022-08-14 18:00

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('users', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='userprofile',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
        ),
    ]
```

these 2 migrations were generated after I added an object manager to StockInfo. My app is otherwise working, but running `python3 manage.py migrate` is what fails. I would like to solve the error and run the migrations successfully without deleting the db and starting from scratch

Comment: code is able to download at https://github.com/codyc4321/stocks_backend

Comment: guess everyone that used to know the errors by heart retired. I ended up dropping my database and deleting the migrations and starting from scratch

Comment: So, everything works fine now?

Comment: yes the problem is if the db was in production and i got this same error i wouldnt be able to fix it. i deleted the entire db (just test db on local) and delete ALL the migrations and started over